# Changing the token length of Spring Boot Elasticsearch pattern matching size

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, elasticsearch

I am using Spring Boot and Elasticsearch and I am trying to use three character searches but the searches only match on five characters or more.

If I have a user name of 'Bob Smith' I can find the match searching for 'Smith' but searching for 'Bob' does not find a match.

I suspect this is something that needs to be changed in my class ''SearchMappingConfig implements HibernateOrmSearchMappingConfigurer'' but I can't find any information about changing the size of the tokens needed to successfully match a result.

My ''@Entity'' tables have ''@FullTextField(analyzer = "english")'' annotations on the fields I want included in the token searches.

How do I change the length of the search match?

Ideally I would like any three letters to form a match, so a search for 'Ron' would match 'Ronald' and 'Laronda'

Elasticsearch 7.14
Spring Boot 2.7.6

I have been reading Spring Boot and Elasticsearch documentation but cannot find any information about changing the match length.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is able to use an Elasticsearch or Lucene client. Our existing project uses Lucene and it would have been a large undertaking to replace that.

The recommended solution is to create new analyzers so that incoming data creates smaller tokens, I didn't want to change analyzers on my existing database.

A lot of the documentation I was able to find pointed to using the Elasticsearch query builder or the Hibernate 5 method of using a wildcard.

I tested our Elasticsearch and found that the wildcard solution would work.

I ended up using the Hibernate 6 method for wildcard searching and it works well.

```java
   SearchResult<DataClass> result = searchSession.search(DataClass.class)
                .where(f -> f.wildcard()
                                .fields(
                                        "firstname",
                                        "lastname",
                                        "username",
                                        "currentLegalName")
                                .matching("*"+searchText.toLowerCase()+"*"))
                .fetch(10);
   long totalHitCount = result.total().hitCount();
   logger.debug("Search results size {}", totalHitCount);
```